# Incorrect XIRR value of installment loan?

Tags: loans, interest-rate, rate-of-return

Using a financial calculator I was able to determine the interest rate of an installment loan with principal of 14975, payments of 444.56 and 60 month term is .2557%.  However, when I put the loan payment schedule in Excel, the XIRR return is .287%.  Can someone help me understand why the XIRR is not .25? Here is how I used excel:

```
    Values  Dates
    -14975  4/1/2014
1   444.56  5/1/2014
2   444.56  6/1/2014
3   444.56  7/1/2014
4   444.56  8/1/2014
5   444.56  9/1/2014
6   444.56  10/1/2014
7   444.56  11/1/2014
8   444.56  12/1/2014
9   444.56  1/1/2015
10  444.56  2/1/2015
11  444.56  3/1/2015
12  444.56  4/1/2015
13  444.56  5/1/2015
14  444.56  6/1/2015
15  444.56  7/1/2015
16  444.56  8/1/2015
17  444.56  9/1/2015
18  444.56  10/1/2015
19  444.56  11/1/2015
20  444.56  12/1/2015
21  444.56  1/1/2016
22  444.56  2/1/2016
23  444.56  3/1/2016
24  444.56  4/1/2016
25  444.56  5/1/2016
26  444.56  6/1/2016
27  444.56  7/1/2016
28  444.56  8/1/2016
29  444.56  9/1/2016
30  444.56  10/1/2016
31  444.56  11/1/2016
32  444.56  12/1/2016
33  444.56  1/1/2017
34  444.56  2/1/2017
35  444.56  3/1/2017
36  444.56  4/1/2017
37  444.56  5/1/2017
38  444.56  6/1/2017
39  444.56  7/1/2017
40  444.56  8/1/2017
41  444.56  9/1/2017
42  444.56  10/1/2017
43  444.56  11/1/2017
44  444.56  12/1/2017
45  444.56  1/1/2018
46  444.56  2/1/2018
47  444.56  3/1/2018
48  444.56  4/1/2018
49  444.56  5/1/2018
50  444.56  6/1/2018
51  444.56  7/1/2018
52  444.56  8/1/2018
53  444.56  9/1/2018
54  444.56  10/1/2018
55  444.56  11/1/2018
56  444.56  12/1/2018
57  444.56  1/1/2019
58  444.56  2/1/2019
59  444.56  3/1/2019
60  444.56  4/1/2019

    xirr    0.28750245
```

Thanks for any help,
John

Comment: Shouldn't be on hold IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out.  XIRR produces effective interest rate while the loan interest rate is nomninal.

Comment: Use IRR on the values column and multiply by 12 to annualise. The answer is 25.57% nominal, compounded monthly.

Comment: If you try to convert your XIRR answer to nominal by ((0.28750245 + 1)^(1/12) - 1) * 12 you get 25.538% not 25.57%. This is because XIRR does not treat months as equal periods, e.g. Feb has 28 days. XIRR is designed for irregular payments

Comment: You can check the result with this [**loan formula**](http://www.financeformulas.net/Loan_Payment_Formula.html) (*linked*).  Using the `IRRmonthlyrate = 0.0213089` the payment are `(IRRmonthlyrate*14975)/(1 - (1 + IRRmonthlyrate)^(-60)) = 444.56`, but using the monthly rate from the XIRR: `XIRRmonthlyrate = ((1 + 0.28750245)^(1/12) - 1) = 0.02128199` the payments come out different: `(XIRRmonthlyrate*14975)/(1 - (1 + XIRRmonthlyrate)^(-60)) = 444.275`.